# Difference between two crontab entries

Tags: linux, cron

I want to run a job weekly using crontab at a specified time.

I run crontab -e as root and add the below entries, one at a time, and wait to see if they ran.

I created two entries, one which works and one which does not.  From the cron docs, I thought they were equivalent, but they must not be because one works and one does not.  I'm looking in /var/log/cron and one produces a run of /my_script.sh and one does not.

My entries:

```
0 7 * * 6 /my_script.sh
0 7 1-31 * 6 /my_script.sh
```

Questions I have:

1. Which is correct?
2. Why is the correct one correct and why is the incorrect one incorrect?

Comment: Which one works and which one doesn't?

Comment: @RamanSailopal are you suggesting I re-word question 1 to be "Which one works and which one doesn't?"  ?